# What is the correct pronunciation of i18n?

Tags: pronunciation

Is *i18n* pronounced *internationalization* or *eye-eighteen-n* or both?

For background on i18n, quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) :

> In computing, internationalization and localization (AmE) or internationalisation and localisation (BrE) are means of adapting computer software to different languages, regional peculiarities and technical requirements of a target locale. 
>   [...]      The terms are frequently abbreviated to the numeronyms *i18n* (where 18 stands for the number of letters between the first i and the last n in the word *internationalization*, a usage coined at Digital Equipment Corporation in the 1970s or 1980s) and *L10n* for *localization*, due to the length of the words.

Comment: Whatever your coworkers use.

Answer (score 12):

Pronouncing it as  "eye-eighteen-n" sounds ugly to me, though I guess (as earlier comment says) if your co-workers have a  office standard better to go with the flow.

However here are some reasons to **say** "*internationalization*" not "*eye-eighteen-n*" ...

1. Wikipedia, says *[...] 18 stands for the number of **letters** between the first i and the last n in the word “internationalization,”*. I'd say **the term is derived for writing not speaking**.
2. *Eye-eighteen-n* implies a verb pronounced *eye-eighteen* - but saying  *"Your task for next week is to eye-eighteen our website"* sounds ridiculous, and in written looks silly : *"[...] is to i18 our website"*. In writing, *i18* simply makes no sense.
3. Lectures like https://youtu.be/iBBkCA1M-mc use *i18n* in text but *internationalisation* when speaking, at least in first few minutes that I watched.
4. Personally I hate pointless jargon

Comment: upvote buddy, I wonder if your name has one letter in between 'k' and 'eran', so you kept it k1eran ;)Just kidding

Comment: Lol. That's true.

Comment: Upvoted for points #1-3, though I disagree with #4. Jargon is rarely pointless or it wouldn't spring up. It might not serve *you*, though.

Comment: I thought the verb would be i14e.  ;-)